# Distinguishing Class and Object Names in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working in Excel VBA.

This property sets Private Histogram

```
Private Histogram As Histogram
Public Property Let CreateSB_Solution(DataSet As Histogram)
    Set Histogram = DataSet
End Property
```

This does not property set Private Histogram

```
Private Histogram As Histogram
Public Property Let CreateSB_Solution(Histogram As Histogram)
    Set Histogram = Histogram
End Property
```

I know I am missing some small nuance but cannot find the proper search criteria to find it.

This does not compile: Method or data member not found.

```
Private Histogram As Histogram
Public Property Let CreateSB_Solution(Histogram As Histogram)
    Set Me.Histogram = Histogram
End Property
```

Comment: You cant `Set Me.Histogram = Histogram` because your class attribute `Histogram` is private.

Comment: try to use a variable name different the type you use, try `Private pHistogram As Histogram` and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `Set Histogram = Histogram` - what is being set to what? which histogram is on the left and which is on the right? - In reality both hold the value of the argument as the most local variable wins.

You can make what you have work by changing `Private Histogram ..` to `Public` but obviously this has consequences, or you can use indirection within `CreateSB_Solution` to call a private property to make the assignment.

Perhaps  the best solution is to not name things in such a way that can lead to these types of problems in the first place, changing the structure of code simply to accommodate more visually appealing monikers is a bad idea.

Either of the below will fix the problem.

```
CreateSB_Solution(fromHistogram As Histogram)

Private CurrentHistogram As Histogram
```